# How can I attribute transfer these points to the curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I want to pass the position of these distributed points to my curve but because the geometry isn't connected to the curve it doesn't work. I can't figure out a way to connect the distributed points to be able to pass this attribute along to the curve.

Is this possible? My initial impression is no. Yet it seems like such a simple task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Transfer Attribute node to transfer the positions of the vertices of the cube to the control points of the curve?[image: like here]

Comment: Oh shit! This isn't quite what I was trying to do but it was the Transfer Attribute node  that worked! Thanks mang